# how to install on an old ubuntu release a higher version of a package which is only available on a newer ubuntu release? I take erlang as an example

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I have an `ubuntu` server system which is `8.04 hardy`, where I am installing rabbitmq. The `rabbitmq` has a dependence of `erlang-nox (>= 1:12.b.3)`, but with the current ubuntu release, the most recent version for erlang-nox I can get is: `1:11.b.5dfsg-11`, via `apt-get`.

So, how can I install the higher version of **erlang(erlang-nox)** with apt-get?

I know the higher version for erlang is available in newer ubuntu release, e.g., on my laptop, the ubuntu is `9.1 karmic`, and the erlang packages are `13.b.1-dfsg-2ubuntu1.1`. how can I get it installed into my `8.04` server system?

I have not tried yet, and I guess manually installing the erlang from the official provided package might work, but I really want a Debian way first, namely, **apt-get**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may declare the Ubuntu Karmic repository in /etc/apt/sources.list, then apt-get update and then install the erlang package of a newer version with apt-get install erlang.

But beware that all the dependencies of the package you install may also be of newer versions. And this will most likely propogate on all the dependency tree. So, you'll have a significant update, and the conflicts may appear. But, AFAIK, that's the only way to do with apt-get.

Comment: Your question isn't an erlang question, but an ubuntu/debian specific question. It is possible to add specific package repos to the /etc/apt/sources.list without breaking the whole system after the next update/upgrade cycle. Take a look for the inxtruction for that here: http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/ . The debian guys called it "pinning" HTH

Comment: Exactly, it is ubuntu specific question. the pinning sounds something helpful, I need to figure out how it works for ubuntu.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem , how did you manage to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.basho.com/Installing-Erlang.html