# How to install specific version of package in ubuntu 14?

Tags: linux, bash

I have to use `makeself` version 2.1.5, which I downloaded using firefox from here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/makeself/2.1.5-1

and installed using command:

```
dpkg -i makeself_2.1.5-1_all.deb
```

How can I write this in the bash script, so the makeself version 2.1.5 will be installed  automatically ? I will need just to launch bash script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186292/how-to-install-on-an-old-ubuntu-release-a-higher-version-of-a-package-which-is-o

Comment: Wrong site, SO is for programming questions. Try here: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install on an old ubuntu release a higher version of a package which is only available on a newer ubuntu release? I take erlang as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186292/how-to-install-on-an-old-ubuntu-release-a-higher-version-of-a-package-which-is-o)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the .deb file link in Firefox, and choose copy link location. That will give you a URL which you can paste into your bash script and use `wget` to download from.

Comment: I heard about better way - use command apt-add-repository to add to /etc/apt/source-lists but I don't know how to add this repository. Do you know how to do this  ?

Comment: It's very dangerous so I am not inclined to tell people how to do this.